# Examples and references of connections on elliptic curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, connections

In studying connections on vector bundles, I am trying to find non trivial examples of connections over an elliptic curve, over $\Bbb P^1_k$ and $\Bbb A^1_k$ for a field $k$.

By a connection on a vector bundle $E$ on a scheme $X$, I mean a morphism $\nabla :E \mapsto E\otimes \Omega^1$ such that $\forall f,e \in \mathcal O_X\times E: \nabla(fe) = f \nabla(e) + df \otimes e$.

Thank you for your help, answers and references.

Comment: What does non-trivial mean for you? Every variety has the natural De Rham connection $\mathcal{O}\to \Omega^1$.

Comment: Thank you @Mohan Actually I meant by non trivial some examples of concrete vector bundle, with concrete connection on it in the case of elliptic curves and projective and affine spaces. For instance taking the curve $y^2=x^3$, how can we construct a vector bundle and a connection on it?

Comment: The curve $y^2=x^3$ is not even smooth, did you really mean that?

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't mean something complicated, a smooth curve like $y^2 = x^3-x$ would do. I am just not familiar with connections and I wanted to understand connections on elliptic curves, or on their function fields. For instance taking the projective curve $E: y^2 = x^3 + ax^2z + bzx^2$,   and taking $f\to df+ f\omega$ where $\omega$ is the differential of the first kind on E. I needed some references or examples to start from scratch as I know quite nothing on the subject. (I know a bit about elliptic curves and scheme theory)